# Need to display page numbers in Table of contents

Tags: puppeteer, css-counter, html-pdf, princexml, puppeteer-sharp

I am just printing the HTML page, I need to show the page numbers opposite to the titles in Table of contents. I investigated a lot, but couldn't find a proper solution. 
While investigating I found [target-counter](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-gcpm-3/#target-counter) but it is not working for me. Seems it is explicitly providing support for [PrinceXML](https://www.princexml.com/), but I am using [puppeteer](https://www.puppeteersharp.com/) to convert HTML content to PDF, since PrinceXML doesn't support .Net Core, I have opted Puppeteer Sharp.
So is there any way I could get page numbers in the table of contents.

[image]

Comment: Can you please show us your attempt @sai

Comment: I have scrapped HTML from the web page and sending it to web API, which is in .net core. In web API I am using puppeteer to convert HTML content to PDF page and exporting it as a byte array to the front end, for downloading purpose.